# Merging columns

Tags: magento2

I'm new to Magento and want to merge customer's firstname and lastname together in grid, but when I try merge it I got an error.

```
Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to undefined method Mageplaza\Affiliate\Model\ResourceModel\Withdraw\Grid\Collection::__() in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0
```

Here is my code;-

```
protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['customer' => $this->getTable('customer_entity')],
            'customer.entity_id = main_table.customer_id',
            array(
            'header'       => $this->__(''),
            'sortable'     => true,
            'index'        => array('firstname', 'lastname'),
            'type'         => 'concat',
            'separator'    => ' ',
            'filter_index' => "CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)",
            )
        );

        return $this;
    }
```

Here is my xml

```
<column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Name</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your join query should be change like this

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['customer' => $this->getTable('customer_entity')],
        'customer.entity_id = main_table.customer_id',
        ['name' => "CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)"]
    );

    return $this;
}
```